# Как спарсить текст находящийся вне тегов | python

Tags: python, парсер

Есть HTML код, с которого нужно спарсить определенный текст и вставить пропущенные слова.

Проблема в том, что при использовании цикла, окончательно в переменной остается самое последнее значение и код выводит:
`В синтаксисе изучаются и RESPONSE1_1, но не как лексические единицы или части речи,    а как RESPONSE1_1 предложения.`
`В синтаксисе изучаются и RESPONSE1_2, но не как лексические единицы или части речи,    а как RESPONSE1_2 предложения.`

Нужно сделать вывод текста:
`В синтаксисе изучаются и RESPONSE1_1, но не как лексические единицы или части речи,    а как RESPONSE1_2 предложения.`

Если кто-то знает решение, то помогите пожалуйста

```
import requests as rqs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re
url = "https://resh.edu.ru/subject/lesson/2700/train/#198352"
link_id = url.split("#")[1]

page = rqs.get(url).text
soup = BS(page, 'html.parser')
# gap_match
gap_match = soup.find_all('div', class_='test-meta js-test-item')
for gm in gap_match:
        get_test_id = gm.get('data-test-id')
        if get_test_id == link_id:
                h = soup.find_all('input', class_='interaction-item')
                for k in h:
                        get_response = k.get('data-interaction-identifier')
                        test = gm.find('div', class_='test-words')
                        test1 = test.get_text('>')
                        test1 = str(test1).replace("    ", "").replace("\n", "").replace(">>>", f"{get_response}") + "\n"
                        print(test1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на replace(">>>", f"{get_response}", 1)

```
import requests as rqs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re
url = "https://resh.edu.ru/subject/lesson/2700/train/#198352"
link_id = url.split("#")[1]

page = rqs.get(url).text
soup = BS(page, 'html.parser')
# gap_match
gap_match = soup.find_all('div', class_='test-meta js-test-item')
for gm in gap_match:
        get_test_id = gm.get('data-test-id')
                if get_test_id == link_id:
                h = soup.find_all('input', class_='interaction-item')#.get('data-interaction-identifier')
                test = gm.find('div', class_='test-words')
                test1 = test.get_text('>')
                for k in h:
                        get_response = k.get('data-interaction-identifier')
                        test1 = str(test1).replace("    ", "").replace("\n", "").replace(">>>", f"{get_response}", 1) + "\n"
                print(test1)
```